Is there a literature repository for glider based PAM research?
Gliders are quickly becoming a key platform for marine passive acoustic monitoring and the technology is rapidly advancing. I'm interested in learning more about current glider-based PAM systems and related research.
Is there a literature repository or comprehensive literature database for this topic?

A NOAA research team has created a public library on Zotero for literature related to PAM Gliders.
https://www.zotero.org/groups/5642642/pam-gliders
This is a new library, and we encourage researchers working in this field to join this public library and to contribute to it.
PAM Gliders can mean different things to different people, and our primary focus is on passive acoustic equipped buoyancy driven autonomous underwater vehicles, though closely related vehicles may be relevant for this library as well.
